# Can we restart wildfly based on output of server.log file?

Tags: shell, wildfly, systemd

I have created a script which would check the server.log file during shutdown and startup as it is proprietary to check the log. And based on that output appropriate step is taken. The problem I am facing now is that whenever i do `grep -m 1 "stopped in" <(tail -n 0 -f /opt/wildfly/standalone/log/server.log)`  it looks in the file. I have tried using `sleep 5s` also but it is of no use. If I separate this command and run separately as new script and run both scripts at the same time then it works just fine. Is there a way so that during stopping wildfly if the output gives *stopped in* then would start as usual and if not *start* and *stop* again.

````
stopwf(){
   systemctl stop wildfly
   grep -m 1 "stopped in" <(tail -n 0 -f /opt/wildfly/standalone/log/server.log)
   rcs=$?;    
}
startwf(){
   systemctl start wildfly
   grep -m 1 "started in" <(tail -n 0 -f /opt/wildfly/standalone/log/server.log)
   rcr=$?;
}
stopwf
if [ "$rcs" -eq 0 ]; then
   startwf
else
   startwf
   while [ "$rcr" -eq 0 ];
   do
     stopwf
     if [ "$rcs" -eq 0 ]; then
        echo -e "\n Stopped Succesfully \n"
        exit 0
     fi
     rcr = $(expr $rcr + 1)
   done 
fi ```

is there a better way to do this. I am stuck in this for a while now.
````

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve? You want to ensure that WildFly will start automatically whenever it gets stopped?

Comment: It is very unclear what you want to do.  You want to look in the log file but can't?  You want to modify the startup script but can't?  Can you add some details as this is confusing as is.